# cat() outputs integers instead of list values in R

Tags: r, console, terminal, cat

Here's the dput for my list:

```
structure(c(5L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("id0", "id1", "id2", "id3",
"id4"), class = "factor")
```

which, when we use `print()` outputs

```
[1] id4 id0 id2
```

Which is what I want minus the `[1]`

To be rid of that, I use `cat()`, but when I do, this is output instead

```
5 3 1
```

Which seems to correspond to the `c(5L,3L,1L)` bit above, but I don't understand why.

Cheers!

Comment: Because your "list" is really a "factor"... convert it to character and you will get what you expect.

Comment: Quick! Submit the answer so I can mark it correct!

Comment: Not very quick, but there you go...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your "list" is really a factor... convert it to character and you will get what you expect.

```
> l <- structure(c(5L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("id0", "id1", "id2", "id3",
+ "id4"), class = "factor")
> cat(l, "\n")
5 3 1
> cat(as.character(l),"\n")
id4 id2 id0
```